# Port forwarding in Ubuntu, from public ip to a client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding

On a VPS with installed Ubuntu server 20.04 and OpenVPN, I need to forward all the traffic from a specific port of the vps public ip, to the same port of a VPN client.

VPS IPs:

```
vps public ip: 1.1.1.1
vps vpn ip: 10.8.0.1
```

Client IP:

```
vpn client ip: 10.8.0.2
```

Port forwarding for the port 587:

```
1.1.1.1:587 >> 10.8.0.2:587
```

I have tried to run the commands on the VPS (1.1.1.1):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:587
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.8.0.2 --dport 587 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1
```

But the packets are not forwarded to the ip 10.8.0.2.

Any idea how iptables should be configured to make a correct port forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this solution which is working as expected:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:587
#exclude "lo" interface, otherwise dns service stop working
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o lo -j MASQUERADE
```